# Contact form 7 hiding my footer

Tags: wordpress, forms, footer, contacts

I have a rather strange problem.
I have created 3 forms for an insurance broker website and of those 3 forms 2 are making my footer shrink in width drastically. The only extra that i added to the forms was some css to have the text fields side by side. I have removed that CSS and still the problem persists. I have also duplicated the working forms page and changed the form but as soon as i do the footer shrinks.

Here is the link to the working footer: http://brokersure.co.za/hail-damage-claim-form/

and the footer thats not working http://brokersure.co.za/motor-accident-claim-form/ Not working

Please help feels like im going crazy.

Many Thanks in advance

Contact Form 7 code from the form that is not working

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:50px;">Particulars of Insured</h3>

<label><h4>Broker Name and Branch:</h4>
    [text* broker-name-branch placeholder ""] </label>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left"><label><h4>Policy Name:</h4>
[text* policy-name placeholder ""]</label></div>

<div id="right"><label><h4>Policy Number:</h4>
[text* policy-number placeholder ""]</label></div><br/><br/>

<label><h4>Occupation or type of Business:</h4>
    [text* occupation-business-type placeholder ""] </label>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left"><label><h4>Email Address:</h4>
[email* email-address placeholder ""]</label></div>

<div id="right"><label><h4>ID Number:</h4>
[text* id-number placeholder ""]</label></div><br/><br/>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left"><label><h4>Cellular Telephone Number:</h4>
[text* cell-number placeholder ""]</label></div>

<div id="right"><label><h4>Telephone Number:</h4>
[text* tel-number placeholder ""]</label></div><br/><br/>

<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:50px;">Loss or Damage Details</h3>

<label><h4>Date and Time of Loss/Damage:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-date-time placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>When was the Loss/Damage Discovered?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-discovered placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Place where Loss/Damage Occured:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-location placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Were Premises Occupied, And by whom?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-premises-occupied placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If not Occupied, when were they last?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-premises-last-occupied placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Purpose of Occupation:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-premises-occupation-purpose placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Describle fully how Loss/Damage occurred, stating how (if applicable) entry was gained to the premises:</h4>
    [textarea* loss-damage-description placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If Loss/Damage caused by another party, give name and address:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-thirdparty placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Have you previously suffered a Loss/Damage?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-previously placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>if so, provide details:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-previously-details placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If Insured, provide name of Insurer:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-insurer-name placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Police Station:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-police-station placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Case Number:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-police-case-number placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Date Reported:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-date-reported placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Has any other party have an interest in the property insured?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-party-interest placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If so, provide details:</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-party-interest-details placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If there any other Insurance covering this Loss/Damage?</h4>
    [text* loss-damage-other-insurance-cover placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>If so, Provide name of Insurer:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-other-insurance-cover-details placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Estimated total value of all the property insured under the policy:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-estimated-value placeholder ""] </label>

<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:50px;">Payment Method</h3>
You may select, for added security, payment of any amount due to you directly into a bank account. Please specify the name, branch and account number. 
 
<label><h4>Name of Bank:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-bank-name placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Name of Account:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-bankaccount-name placeholder ""] </label>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left"><label><h4>Branch:</h4>
[text* loss-damage-bank-branch placeholder ""]</label></div>

<div id="right"><label><h4>Account Number:</h4>
[text* loss-damage-bank-account-number placeholder ""]</label></div><br/><br/>

<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:50px;">Declaration and Signature</h3>

<hr>

We declare that we have suffered loss of or damage to the property enumerated on the list below and that the said property was in our possession immediately prior to the said loss/damage which occurred in the circumstances described above. 

<hr>

We the undersigned, declare the aforegoing particulars to be true in every respect. We understand that if any part of the claim or if anyone else on our behalf uses fraudulent means or devices relating to the submission of this claim, of if the loss is because of a deliberate act on our part then we will not be entitled to any benefits or indemnification in terms of this claim. 

<hr>

<label><h4>Name of Insured:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-insured-name placeholder ""] </label>

<label><h4>Date:</h4>
    [text loss-damage-signed-date placeholder ""] </label>

<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top:50px;">Click to comfirm:</h3>

[submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close all the usages of this tag:

```
<div class="clearfix">
```

In general replace all occurrences of this:

```
</label></div><br/><br/>
```

with this:

```
</label></div></div><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page and i think this happens due to not correctly complete your HTML tags.Please check this by pressing the CTRL+U there are some tags that not correctly closed. So please check the HTML structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shah thanks for the response ... The HTML is auto generated from the Contact Form 7 plugin all i have added is the field shortcodes and of course the css to have the fields side by side.

Comment: Could you please provide what you had inserted in the Contact form 7 ?

Comment: Okay. Reason is only in proper HTML structure. I didn't help you without contact form 7's form. Just check properly in contact form 7.

Thanks.

Comment: I reviewed your HTML and finds that your footer section inside the "<form>". If you manually get it out from "<form>" to your inside the "<div class-'container'> then you got your result.

Comment: I reviewed your HTML above. Please close the "<div class='clearfix'>" tags. Not any of from them closed properly.

Thanks.